# How can I get Indy IdSMTPRelay log of the SMTP conversation?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I use Indy10's TIDSMTPRelay to relay some messages out and it works great. However, I need a log of the actual SMTP conversation with the counterparty and the OnDirectSMTPStatus and OnStatus events do not provide this as far as I can see. How can I get to the SMTP log?

Comment: For logging to a file, drop or create dynamically a `TIdLogFile` component, assign it the `FileName` property value, connect it with the `TIdSMTPRelay` by the `Intercept` property and set `Active` property of it to True to start logging. Enjoy your log! :-)

Comment: Thanks TLama, that works. But, it logs the whole email I'm relaying. Can I override what it logs easily?

Comment: Sorry, but this I would let answer someone more interested in this topic. My guess is that by using of the `TIdLogFile` don't, but maybe if you implement your logging through the `TIdLogEvent`, you'd be able to refine what you want to log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using TIdLogEvent implementing the OnSent and OnReceived events.